# Generic logging function wrapper

Tags: python, python-3.x

So what I'm trying to do is essentially take a bunch of pre-existing functions from commonly used libraries (such as subprocess,shutil,etc...) and wrap them in a function that will ouput what the function is doing as well as errors if any occur. My current code looks something like this.

```
def copytree(self,*args, **kwargs):
    self.debug(f":- Copying tree from \"{args[0]}\" to \"{args[1]}\"")
    try:
        shutil.copytree(*args,**kwargs)
    except Exception as e:
        self.error(f":- Failed to copy tree from \"{args[0]}\" to \"{args[1]}\" ; \"{e}\"")
        return False        
    self.debug(f":- Done")
    return True
```

I feel like there is probably a better way to do this in which there is a generic wrapper that can be used on any function but I am having trouble conceptualizing it. I'm also not sure if there is a way to account for functions that don't raise exceptions within said generic wrapper.

Also: self.debug and self.error are both just from the logging module

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use [function decorator](https://www.thecodeship.com/patterns/guide-to-python-function-decorators/) and [logging](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/logging.html) module.

Here is a simple and dirty example :

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)


# decorator
def logged(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            logging.info("started '{0}', parameters : {1} and {2}".
                         format(func.__name__, args, kwargs))
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            logging.exception(e)
    return wrapper


@logged
def foo(val):
    print(val/2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo("a")
```

Output :

> INFO:root:started 'foo', parameters : ('a',) and {}
>
> ERROR:root:unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/xxxx.py", line 9, in wrapper
>       return func(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "C:/Users/xxxx.py", line 17, in foo
>       print(val/2)
>
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'