# Is there a way to call a function each time another function is called?

Tags: python, function

Say I have the following code:

```
def foo():
    print("I'm a function")

def bar():
    print("Me, too!")
```

Is there an elegant way to call a third function each time any function in this script is called? I would like to avoid having to call the third function from within the function body as my actual script contains a lot of functions, so some global way would be nice in order to avoid excessive repetition.

Comment: You could write a decorator to call the third function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50415666/generic-logging-function-wrapper may give some ideas

Comment: @tevemadar Thank you, this should be what I'm looking for